# detect if computer is not member of at least one group

Tags: powershell, active-directory-group

I have a need to detect computer objects that are not a member of at least one group.  I have come up with this script, but instead of listing just the machines that are not a member of at least one group, it returns all workstations.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | where {
  $_.memberof -notmatch 'Group1' -and
  $_.memberof -notmatch 'Group2' -and
  $_.memberof -notmatch 'Group3'
} | Format-Table Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MemberOf` property contains a list of distinguished names. You can't check if it doesn't contain something with the `-notmatch` operator. Instead get a list of the distinguished names of your groups:

```
$groups = 'Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3' |
          ForEach-Object { Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -eq '$_'" } |
          Select-Object -Expand DistinguishedName
```

and check if the `MemberOf` property doesn't contain any of them:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Where-Object {
  -not (Compare-Object $groups $_.MemberOf -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent)
} | Format-Table Name
```

The `Compare-Object` is required, because you need to check if one array contains any of the elements of another array. Something like `$_.MemberOf | Where-Object {$groups -contains $_}` would also work.

Note that the `MemberOf` property does *not* include the primary group of a computer. If the primary group must also not be one of the groups from your list you need an additional check in the `Where-Object` filter:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Where-Object {
  -not (Compare-Object $groups $_.MemberOf -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent) -and
  $groups -notcontains $_.PrimaryGroup
} | Format-Table Name
```

Comment: I must say, this is a better answer.  I'd use this one, OP.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `-NotMatch` operator, which will evaluate to true if the entries do not exactly match.  You'd be better served using `-NotContain`, like so

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | where {$.memberof -notContains 'Group1' -and $.memberof -notContains 'Group2' -and $_.memberof -notContains 'Group3'} | Format-Table Name
```

Comment: `MemberOf` contains a list of distinguished names. Checking if a list of group distinguished names contains a group name will always return `$false`.